# how to work create virtual table in sqlite and access?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am working with sqlite in iphone application. what i want to do is like i will get the data from data base using "select * from tablename". but i don't want to access all the rows at a time. I know that we can use cursor for this. I know how to write them in MySql procedures. but I want it to be implemented in my app. [Virtual table]http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#xconnect here they explained like we have to create  virtual table to use cursor. so if any body worked with this can you explain me how to do that with some coding example...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying too hard. SQLite only fetches one row at a time. There is a function call that will obtain all the rows, but the documentation specifically states what it is doing.